# Python AWS Lambda + Pusher ImportError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm having trouble making and using a python deployment package for AWS Lambda which uses the pip package Pusher. This is the error I get.

```
No module named ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification: ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/Lambda.py", line 3, in pusherTest
    pusher = Pusher(app_id=u'154504', key=u'121300e92c61a1fe43bc', secret=u'bfff467a2b6551f19226')
  File "/var/task/pusher/pusher.py", line 42, in __init__
    from pusher.requests import RequestsBackend
  File "/var/task/pusher/requests.py", line 12, in <module>
    import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
  File "/var/task/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification import SUBJ_ALT_NAME_SUPPORT
ImportError: No module named ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification
```

Here are the steps to recreate my issue for anyone who wants to try. I've even included a dummy Pusher app in the free sandbox in case you've never used it.

1. Create new virtual environment using `virtualenv`

   vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Lamdba$ virtualenv env
   New python executable in /home/vagrant/Code/Lamdba/env/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
2. Activate virtual environment to install packages.

   vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Lamdba$ source env/bin/activate
   (env) vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Lamdba$
3. Install pusher package

`pip install pusher`

4. Zip `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages` into a zip file with a py script with code in it that looks like this

   `from pusher import Pusher
   def pusherTest(context, event):
       pusher = Pusher(app_id=u'154504', key=u'121300e92c61a1fe43bc', secret=u'bfff467a2b6551f19226')
       pusher.trigger('testchannel', 'testevent', {u'some': u'data'})`
5. Upload to Lambda and test function.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is failing to import the `ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification` module, so you have to make sure that:

1. The `ndg-httpsclient` package has been installed in the virtual environment. It's a dependency of the pusher package, so I guess it's been indeed installed, but confirm it with `pip freeze`.
2. You zip the content of `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, not the directory. AWS is expecting the `ndg` package to be in the root of your Lambda application.

Comment: It is int stalled via pip freeze and I did zip the contents of that folder not the folder. I will make that more clear in question.